# Multiple associations between entity and list of entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my database lets say I have two tables, tblFoo and tblBar

tblFoo has the columns

```
ID, Name, SomeFooThing, BarGroup, DeviceID, CountryCode, UserID
```

tblBar has the columns

```
ID, Name, SomeBarThing, BarGroup, DeviceID, CountryCode, UserID
```

I have two entity classes:

```
[Table("tblFoo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeFooThing { get; set; }
    public int BarGroup { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblFoo")]
public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeBarThing { get; set; }
    public int BarGroup { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

How would I make the association between Foo and Bar?

If I was to do this in SQL I would do (to give you more of an idea)

```
SELECT tblBar.ID, tblBar.Name, tblBar.SomeBarThing, tblBar.BarGroup, 
tblBar.DeviceID, tblBar.CountryCode, tblBar.UserID, Foo.ID as FooID 
FROM tblBar INNER JOIN tblFoo ON tblBar.BarGroup=tblFoo.BarGroup AND 
tblBar.DeviceID=tblFoo.DeviceID AND tblBar.CountryCode=tblFoo.CountryCode 
AND tblBar.UserID=tblFoo.UserID
```

I am using entity framework 6

Comment: You need to add a foreign key assignment to the two models. Check out [Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx). BTW, your SQL statement doesn't show any relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Changed the statement. 

How can I add multiple foreign keys though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `Foo` navigation property inside `Bar` class:

```
[Table("tblBar")]
public class Bar
{
    // (...)

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can perform following query:

```
var query = from b in ctx.Bars
            let f = b.Foo
            select { ... }
```

EF will add necessary `JOIN` for you.

Comment: Yes, but would it take into account the DeviceID, CountryCode, BarGroup and UserID?

Comment: Yes, it would. Or better: it should.

Comment: Would that simply be because of the naming of the columns? Just trying to understand. What if the columns had different names but I wanted them to equal on the join?

Comment: Foreign key has to contain all Primary Key columns from the table you're linking too. That's how it works. But I may not get your question correctly. Do you wan't PK to be FK at the same time? If so, you have to mark them as FK, using `[ForeignKey]` attribute.

Comment: `ID`, `DeviceID`, `CountryCode` and `UserID` are all primary keys on both tables. 

So does that mean I should have `Key` and `ForeignKey` on them?

Comment: Yes, if you need 1-to-1 relationship. To get 1-to-n (and that's how your model looks like, you have collection of `Bar`s in `Foo` entity) you need separate columns to handle FK in `Bar` entity. These columns will be added by EF automatically because of navigation properties. And number of these columns will be exactly the same as number of PK columns in `Foo` table.

Comment: Could you post an example please? :)